# SQL Reporting count of parameter in a column

Tags: sql, count, ssrs-2008

I am working in SSRS 3.0 with a SQL table including the following fields:

```
ApptID    BookedBy   ConfirmedBy   CancelledBy
```

I also have a parameter setup to select which users to filter by (matches data in the `BookedBy`, `ConfirmedBy` and `CancelledBy` columns) called `@Scheduler` (which is a multi vale parameter/array).

I need to get a count for booked, confirmed and scheduled for how many times any value in the Scheduler parameter shows up in that column.

Basically:

```
COUNT(BookedBy IN (@Scheduler)) AS BookedCount
```

Can anyone help me out with the syntax for doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: I still need access to the "raw" dataset.  I would have to make several separate queries to use GROUP BY

Comment: have you looked at cubes or grouping sets/roll up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT Count(BookedBy = @Scheduler) as [BookedCount],
        Count(ConfirmedBy = @Scheduler) as [ConfirmedCount],
        Count(CancelledBy = @Scheduler) as [CancelledCount]
 FROM tablename
 WHERE BookedBy = @Scheduler OR 
       ConfirmedBy = @Scheduler OR
       CancelledBy = @Scheduler
```

NB - Not tested might contain typos

---

If your input is a list separated by commas you can convert that to a table.  See a reference like this:

http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/sqlarrays.aspx

For this use case I'd recommend one of the solutions that saves the result in a CTE (since you only need to convert your input once and this will be fastest)

Then you could use that table (called sTable with column name) like this:

```
 SELECT Count(Bo.Name) as [BookedCount],
        Count(Co.Name) as [ConfirmedCount],
        Count(Ca.Name) as [CancelledCount]
 FROM tablename
 LEFT JOIN sTable Bo ON BookedBy = Bo.name
 LEFT JOIN sTable Co ON ConfirmedBy = Co.name 
 LEFT JOIN sTable Ca ON CancelledBy = Ca.name
```

---

I guess this will work but it does not seem as nice as the others:

```
 SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE BookedBy in (@Scheduler)) AS [BookedCount],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ConfirmedBy in (@Scheduler)) as [ConfirmedCount],
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE CancelledBy in (@Scheduler)) as [CancelledCount]
```

Comment: No luck.  I think the issue might be that @Scheduler is really an array, hence the desire for the "IN" function.

Comment: @Thildarmar - an array with commas?

Comment: Think I might be confusing terminology here.  It is a multi-value parameter from Report Builder.  I am not sure exactly the format the array takes, I would assume comma delimited.  Basically the user is presented with the list of possible schedulers (all possible values for the BookedBy field), the then select which they wish to run the report against.